# insertOne method modifies input query object

Tags: mongodb

```js
userInfo = {
      name: 'Magical Mr. Mistoffelees',
      email: 'magicz@cats.com',
      password: 'somehashedpw'
}

await users.insertOne(userInfo, {
  writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 100 },
})

console.log(userInfo)

{
      name: 'Magical Mr. Mistoffelees',
      email: 'magicz@cats.com',
      password: 'somehashedpw',
      _id: 6279884c2b402a8f82efa162
}
```

Is this expected behavior? It added an `_id` field.

Comment: The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array as default mongo use it as ObjectId.

Comment: that's not the point of though. The object `userInfo` was modified. This doesn't right at all.

Comment: It is expected, if expectations come from reading the docs https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/classes/Collection.html#insertOne not from personal beliefes about rights and wrongs.

Comment: @AlexBlex that's not quite the same thing. I understand that `_id` will be added to the document that gets stored in the database. But the input object `userInfo` is not a document. It is merely an object that contains information about the new document that will be created and then inserted into the database

Comment: If you are working with `typescript` and `mongoose`, for example, you can have an interface without the `_id` for internal BE use.

Comment: Free, I see you point, but de-facto "document" and "object" are interchangable terms in mongodb-nodejs docs. Regardless of semantic, the page behind the link explicitly says "mutating the document". You can argue about the "document" thing, but "mutating" is pretty clear and means "the parameter will be changed".